# React Modal makes page goes down

Tags: reactjs, redux, modal-dialog

Don't know why when i click to open the modal the main screen goes down as the modal goes on top of it:

https://github.com/RodPin/Modal-with-Redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone ahead and refactored your application. You have a lot of mistakes that are holding your application back.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/xj553k7nno

**Please read the following notes carefully**:

- Use the npm package `react-redux` ([documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/docs/introduction/quick-start)) for connecting and dispatching to `redux`
- Separate your `containers` from your `components`: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0
- When using `prop-types`, I'd recommend defining `propTypes` outside of your class (I prefer it out of the `class` or `function` and before or after the `export`). See this for more [details](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#usage).
- Create `actions` that manipulate Redux's `state` and create `types` that handle what `state` to manipulate.
- Common convention for Redux `actions` is to `return` a `type` and `payload` (although sometimes a `payload` may not be necessary) and for all `reducers` to expect that `type` and `payload` from the action.
- Use `switch` statements instead of nested `if` and `else` statements for your `reducers`.
- When `import`ing please follow this order:

  - 1.) Node Modules
  - 2.) Components/Containers/Actions/Reducers/Helper functions
  - 3.) Stylesheets
- Do not nest invalid HTML elements: `<p><div/></p>` (`div` can not appear as a `child` of `p`)
- Do not use vague prop names: `close`, `open`, ...etc. Instead be more declarative: `closeModal`, `openModal`, ...etc.
- Do not use underscores `_` as this is not a common JavaScript naming convention
- Reduce repetitive code with reusable components (for example: `ModalColor`)!
- In this example, React `state` is not needed to update Redux's `state`. Redux can control its own `state` via the `actions` and `reducers`.
- Use `<Fragment></Fragment>` or `<></>` when you need to encapsulate JSX elements that don't need a containing HTML element.
- Simplify your application structure:

  ```
   ├── build
   |   ├── css
   |   |   ├── main.[contenthash:8].css
   |   |   └── main.[contenthash:8].css.map
   |   ├── js
   |   |   ├── main.[hash].js
   |   |   └── main.[hash].js.map
   |   ├── media
   |   |   └── [hash].[ext]
   |   └── favicon.ico
   |   └── index.html
   |
   ├── public
   |   ├── favicon.ico
   |   └── index.html
   |
   ├── src
   |   ├── actions
   |   ├── components
   |   ├── containers
   |   ├── images
   |   ├── reducers
   |   ├── routes
   |   ├── store
   |   ├── styles (global)
   |   ├── tests
   |   ├── types
   |   ├── utils
   |   ├── index.js
   |   ├── serviceWorker.js
   |   └── setupTests.js
   |
   ├── .gitignore
   ├── README.md
   ├── package.lock.json
   └── package.json
  ```